# DateTime Formatting on Azure hosted site

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, csvhelper

so my tech stack is: 
asp.net core 1.1 hosted on Azure using CSV Helper to read CSVs into a SQL database (in azure).

ok so the problem i'm facing is when i'm using CSV helper locally its all fine, the date format is reading it as per the CSV file into the format i want (dd/mm/yyyy i'm in sydney).

when i import a file hosted on the azure site.. my date formats are screwed (they are converting to the US).

how do i go about importing those dates correctly using CSV Helper?

in my startup.cs i have the following:

```
    //Currently only supports en-AU culture. This forces datetime and number formats to the en-AU culture regardless of local culture
    var auCulture = new CultureInfo("en-AU");
    var supportedCultures = new[] { auCulture };
    services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(auCulture, auCulture);
        options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
        options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
    });
```

and i'm using UTC across the site, but since these datetimes are coming from CSVHelper, that seems to be screwing up my format.

any ideas?

cheers,

Comment: Have you isolated whether the problem is in the parsing or in later formatting? Have you tried specifying the culture info explicitly as `csv.Configuration.CultureInfo = ...`?

Comment: thanks @JonSkeet ! as always, legendary. pop it in as an answer and i'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to make sure `CsvHelper` always uses one particular culture, you can set it explicitly:

```
csv.Configuration.CultureInfo = auCulture;
```

You should bear in mind, however, that a `DateTime` doesn't "store" a format - so once you've parsed the value in the CSV file, you've just got a `DateTime` value... you may well need to explicitly control any later formatting of that value for the UI or other output.